# Leaflet: add same layer to two different maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, leaflet, mapbox

I am displaying two different `leaflet` `map`s in the same page. After a certain event. I want a `Polyline` to appear on both of them. I would like to avoid, if possible, to create a copy and keep two different variables.

I am trying yo use the following:

```
var line_coordinates = [[1,2],[3,4]];
var my_polyline = L.polyline(line_coordinates);
my_polyline.addTo(map1);
my_polyline.addTo(map2);
```

However, if I run the above code, the `Polyline` will be displayed only on the `map2`.

Afterwords, I will need to change again its coordinates to some `new_line_coordinates`, and I will run the following:

```
my_polyline.setLatLngs(new_line_coordinates);
my_polyline.redraw();
```

The `polyline` should now appear updated to the new coordinates. However, again, it appears only on `map2`.

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: Not possible to add the same object to two different maps.  There is only one map property.

Comment: I think you should a create a "model", then two polygons being drawn and redrawn based on the data in this model.

Comment: @LSA What do you mean by model? Could you make a short example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As geocodezip mentioned in a comment, adding a polyline to a map sets the polyline object's `this._map` instance variable. Therefore, there is no way to have the object rendered on both maps with the way in which it is currently implemented.

You can view the relevant source code [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/101d0df5f7c493fe23f066588e9f801c54fa4511/src/layer/vector/Path.js#L39-L40).

Answer (score 2):

You can't add the same layer to multiple Leaflet maps. But I had a similar problem using a more complex GeoJSON layergroup and ultimately solved it by getting the GeoJSON object from the layer using `toGeoJSON()` and using it to create a new layer for the second map. For a simple polyline, you could use `getLatLngs()`. So:

```
var line_coordinates = [[1,2],[3,4]];
var my_polyline = L.polyline(line_coordinates);
my_polyline.addTo(map1);
var new_polyline = L.polyline(line_coordinates);
new_polyline.addTo(map2);
```

should work, as would:

```
var line_coordinates = [[1,2],[3,4]];
var my_polyline = L.polyline(line_coordinates);
my_polyline.addTo(map1);
var my_polyline_latlngs = my_polyline.getLatLngs();
var new_polyline = L.polyline(my_polyline_latlngs);
new_polyline.addTo(map2);
```