# How to create leaflet tileLayer object on node js and send it as response of express API

Tags: node.js, express, leaflet

So the problem that I am facing right now is that I am able to create leaflet object in node js and sending the response as object using express. Now this api is working fine but the I am unable to consume the API response in front-end.

At the back-end for API I am using express,leaflet and mock-browser(for simulating browser at the backend) npm modules but the response differs if I create the same object in front-end.

How am I supposed to create identical object in node js as that of front-end and consume it on simple webpage?

code for my api is as follows:

```
const MockBrowser = require('mock-browser').mocks.MockBrowser;
const mock = new MockBrowser();
global['window'] = mock.getWindow();
global['document'] = mock.getDocument();
global['navigator'] = mock.getNavigator();
const express = require('express');
const L = require('leaflet');
const app = express()
const port = 3000


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

let overlay = L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=your_mapbox_access_token', {
                  attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
                  maxZoom: 18,
                  id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
                  accessToken: 'your_mapbox_access_token'
              });

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send({ data: overlay })
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App running on port ${port}.`)
});
```

I want to consume the response of this API in a webpage by running function below:

```
// after setting up leaflet environment is JS
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);   
function mapit(){
            $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/',
            success: function(res){
                res['data'].addTo(mymap);
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Note first that any http request conveys only strings. Such strings can encode serialized data. But not JS objects.

Comment: @ghybs that means in my case we can't deserialize our object literal sent over http?

Comment: Indeed. If you inspect your network response, you should see your object with an attempt to serialize it, very probably missing lot of pieces.

Comment: This is an extreme case of the general one that you can't share a layer between 2 maps - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235075/leaflet-add-same-layer-to-two-different-maps